# Meteor.js Cordova App Failing DOCTYPE

Tags: cordova, meteor, phonegap-plugins

So, I'm building a cross-platform meteor app that uses the [BarcodeScanner Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner). I can build using:

```
    meteor build cordova --server localhost:3000
```

But when I try to run using:

```
    meteor
```

I get these errors

```
       cordova/android/project/assets/www/application/head.html:1:Expected one of: <body>, <head>, <template>
       cordova/android/project/assets/www/application/index.html:1:Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html> for you)
       cordova/android/project/build/outputs/lint-results-release-fatal.html:1: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor sets <!DOCTYPE html>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Did you follow what the error messages stated (removing `<html>` from those files and adding a valid tag in `<head>`)?

Comment: @jordanwillis But I have over 75 files giving me this same error. Going through all of them is slightly difficult.

Comment: What are those files? Ones you created in your app?

Comment: @jordanwillis They're auto generated.

Comment: @jordanwillis When I run build cordova they all appear.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2886) will help? Try outputting your cordova build in a different folder than your project folder.

Comment: @jordanwillis How would I do that?

Comment: Use the [`--directory`](http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild) option and give it a path outside your app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you did not provide an output directory when you did the cordova build and your meteor app folder is now populated with built js/html files.

To fix this, delete these files from your meteor app directory and next time you build use the [`--directory`](http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild) option to specify a path outside your app folder.

You might also find the [Meteor Mobile Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html) helpful if you are not already using it.

Comment: I have done that and it works perfectly, but now when I go to meteor run I get an error about cordova-plugin-compat

Comment: While removing plugins cordova-plugin-whitelist from Cordova project:
   Cordova error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-compat". Please
   try adding it again. I then add it again and it still gives me the same error, over and over.